# How to visualize an distance matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have an distance matrix (as DataFrame) as below for which I would like to create an plot like the second graph to visualize the distances. Is there any available plot object in Python can visualize distance matrix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Huh? The image seems to be literally pinched from the duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any of these:

1. [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/)- its a python package which maybe used to plot graphs.
2. [Graphviz - Graph Visualization Software](http://www.graphviz.org/) or
   [graphviz 0.4.10](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz)

For a start maybe go through [Generating Graph Visualizations with pydot and Graphviz](https://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/generating_graphs_with_pydot/)