# Plotting a 2D plot from a distance matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

I have a distance matrix:

```
dis_matrix = torch.tensor([[ 0.0000, 20.2615, 20.6478, 21.8596, 20.5779],
        [20.2615,  0.0000, 21.4059, 22.5908, 21.6969],
        [20.6478, 21.4059,  0.0000, 21.3755, 21.4672],
        [21.8596, 22.5908, 21.3755,  0.0000, 24.2236],
        [20.5779, 21.6969, 21.4672, 24.2236,  0.0000]])
```

Where the names are:

```
names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

How can I visualize it in 2D in `matplotlib`? That is, plotting the name of each variable on a 2D plot that will be `x` distance away from the other values (where `x` is clearly the distances from the distance matrix).

There are many answers using `networkx` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137112/how-to-visualize-an-distance-matrix-in-python)), or using `MDS` (like [here](https://medium.com/dataseries/multidimensional-scaling-for-dissimilarity-visualization-9fb061396cf3)), but I just want to create a simple 2D plot using the distances.

Comment: are you sure that this can be visualised in 2d.  Consider three items A,B,C.  A is close to B, but very far from C, but C is very close to B.  This is perfectly fine in a distance matrix, but cant be shown in 2D.

Comment: Why don't you like [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/)? I would quess that this is the simplest way for a 2D plot

Comment: @ChristianSloper It's even worse than that. In fact you can have a valid finite metric space  as in this question (where the triangle inequality holds) but that's still no guarantee that a (isometric) planar embedding exists.

Comment: Hmm I see your point guys. @max the reason I don't want to use networkx is because I don't care for the edges. I just need the plot to have the points with their names on it